# Meteor Velocity; using CLI getting timeout

Tags: meteor, jasmine, circleci, meteor-velocity

Simple tests are timing-out intermittently on CircleCi. This only happens on CircleCi, locally on OSX, all testing is fine. Anyone having success with CircleCi specifically?

Running tests should be straightforward, but no one at CircleCI, or at the velocity forum have been able to solve this.

I've used the simple example tests from sanjo:jasmine. Intermittently, velocity hangs and goes to timeout. No errors. Nothing informative in logs. Strangely it did work once on CircleCi, and then never again.

The test command is simply:

```
meteor --test
```

The output I get doesn't print any tests:

```
stream error Network error: ws://localhost:3000/websocket: connect ECONNREFUSED
[[[[[ ~/app ]]]]]                  

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

In the .meteor/local/log/jasmine-client-unit.log this is the last line:

```
Chrome 38.0.2125 (Linux): Executed 0 of 0^[[32m SUCCESS^[[39m (0 secs / 0 secs)
^[[1A^[[2KChrome 38.0.2125 (Linux): Executed 0 of 0^[[31m ERROR^[[39m (0.023 secs / 0 secs)
```

I confirmed that the versions are the same Meteor 1.03.2, Node 0.10.33, Phantomjs 2.0.0, Chrome 40. Sorry that I can't provide a reproducible repository, it's a very intermittent error likely related to environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try `meteor --test --once`

The once might be the reason it's not finishing up

Comment: thanks, but the issue is it doesn't ever run the tests. The log error is quite cryptic

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

It turns out that jasmine end to end testing recommends webdriver as well. So my advice below should still apply for jasmine.

**/edit**

What framework? If it is cucumber, the issue is the phantomjs version that gets installed doesn't install the right binary for some reason.

For that reason, in CI, you need to install phantom and set the path as an environment variable.

```
npm install -g phantomjs
export PHANTOM_PATH=`which phantomjs`
```

This will tell webdriver to use your path of the correctly installed binary instead of the wrong version.

We should really just fix Cucumber.js to not fail silently.

The other error you are seeing about websockets is just --test not connecting right on startup, it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: I'm using Meteor and Velocity, and the sanjo:jasmine package for Velocity. In the default configuration it uses chrome.